# Is it possible to destructure function arguments with ternary assignment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to be able to destructure function arguments with ternary assignment.

```
const fn = (size ? 'large' : 'small') => [
  `lots${size}`,
  `of${size}`,
  `values${size}`,
];

fn(true); // imageLarge
fn(); // imageSmall
```

Comment: It's not 'destructuring', not even defaulting to some value, you just have a function returning some value *based on* the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using default parameters:

```js
const fn = (isLarge, size = isLarge ? 'large' : 'small') => [
  `lots${size}`,
  `of${size}`,
  `values${size}`,
];

console.log(fn(true));

console.log(fn(false));
```

Comment: while that works, it is not (very) safe to use it, because a random content for the second parameter would destroy the intention of the function.

Comment: Indeed, but you can always limit the number of allowed parameters using something like lodash's [`_.ary()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#ary).

Comment: It's hacky but it's great, nicely done! Did not realize the assignment was progressive. I wouldn't use this code in prod, but fun to kick around :D

Answer (score 2):

No, you may move it inside of the template literal.

```
const fn = size => `image${size ? 'large' : 'small'}`;
```

Use case with keeping `size`.

```js
const fn = size => ((x = size ? 'large' : 'small') => [
    `lots${x}`,
    `of${x}`,
    `values${x}`
])();

console.log(fn(true));
console.log(fn());
```

Comment: Updated the use-case above, I would like the ternary to be reused in the function

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the ternary operator within the [Template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const fn = (size) => `image${size ? 'large' : 'small'}`;

console.log(fn(true)); // imageLarge
console.log(fn()); // imageSmall
```

---

**Update :** In the second case update the size value within the function.

```js
const fn = (size) => size = size ? 'large' : 'small', [
  `lots${size}`,
  `of${size}`,
  `values${size}`,
];

console.log(fn(true));
console.log(fn());
```

Comment: Updated the use-case above, I would like the ternary to be reused in the function

Comment: Clever use of the comma operator. I had to remove the part of my answer that said it couldn't be done as a one-liner. :)

Comment: You don’t need parens around the arg when it’s one, drops 2 chars!

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to set a new variable inside the function if you don't want to repeat the ternary.

```js
const fn = islarge => {
  var size = islarge ? 'large' : 'small';
  return [
    `lots${size}`,
    `of${size}`,
    `values${size}`,
  ];
};

console.log(fn(true));
console.log(fn());
```